# What circuit allows me to drive positive kV level pulses to antennas and over spark gaps to earth ground?

Tags: high-voltage, generator, pulse

Ideally I would like 0-6kV pulses with adjustable frequency, but I could settle for 4kV and 40kHz.

Pulses should be sharp as possible. Someone suggested a PWM module with a mosfet inside and to drive an ignition coil. Through the HV terminal and spark plug to earth ground. I think this would produce too high of a voltage. Like this ZK-PP2K (https://supereyes.ru/img/instructions/ZK_PP_manual.pdf)

The output current can be fairly low like 30mA. Input could be 12v DC. I found this single terminal neon tube exiter https://www.amazing1.com/content/download/NEONIZER_INS.pdf but there is no frequency control there.

Some NSTs might fall into this area, but I don't know how to convert those to single output terminals. They also have ground fault interruptors, so pulsing through spark gaps to earth ground might be off the picture.

There are many HV pulse generators out there with fancy builtin options, but I would rather spend 50$ rather than 2k$

I am aware that working with these voltages is not without risk.

Comment: A car engine car ignition circuit sounds fit for purpose with slight modification. It depends on the load capacitance mainly.

Comment: For what purpose is this? What sharpness do you really require? What PRF (pulse repetition frequency) range?  What load impedance, is it just sparking to a target or should it be wired? How are you verifying that the pulse is as desired?

Comment: Sharpness is a particularly interesting question, because "as sharp as possible" could be picoseconds (maybe even less), which is achievable at great expense.  One must never be careless with "as X as possible" statements, because what is possible may be quite far from what one really requires.

Comment: Maybe we forget the sharpness. Would be nice to control the frequency all the way to MHz range (maybe not say Hz, since it is not a wave per se), but 50k pulses/s would be ok. I can take even AC and then maybe half wave rectify it to pulses. Lets say wired then. Difficult to define the exact imp, when the actual application is so vaque atm. Battery operated with adjustable voltage and frequency. Lets say I want to pulse a coil that is earth grounded at the other end with a plant growing in the cernter of the coil. I would think any high voltage can push through the coil into the earth

Comment: We have a grant to study EM effects on the biome. We are mostly interested on possible effects on plants, microbes and pests. If copper tape won't work on slugs, would some EM based method work? Can we affect growth, diseases or maybe attract positive fungi? We basically have a big blackboard full on ideas that we update. Nothing is too weird to be left out. We have penicillin because of an accident. So I'm sorry if this type of research is not serious enough, but we think it is. Also it pays the bills...